# OpenCv, Insufficient memory error

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I created this code in Opencv and after about 900 frames, this error appears:

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 921600 bytes) in function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxalloc.cpp, line 52
```

but I have initialized the variables once.
Here is the code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     IplImage * image;
     CvCapture * capture = cvCaptureFromCAM ( 0 );
     while ( 1 ){
         image = cvCreateImage ( cvSize ( 640,480 ) , 8, 3 );
         image = cvQueryFrame ( capture );
         cvShowImage ( "test", image );
         cvWaitKey ( 10 );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constantly creating new images with `cvCreateImage` without using and, more importantly, without releasing them anywhere.

Just remove this line (it does not do anything other than eat up your memory):

```
image = cvCreateImage ( cvSize ( 640,480 ) , 8, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call `cvReleaseImage` at some point.